# what is the difference between if-else statement and torch.where in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, automatic-differentiation

See the code snippet:

```py
import torch
x = torch.tensor([-1.], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.where(x > 0., x, torch.tensor([2.], requires_grad=True))
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

The output is `tensor([0.])`, but

```py
import torch
x = torch.tensor([-1.], requires_grad=True)
if x > 0.:
    y = x
else:
    y = torch.tensor([2.], requires_grad=True)
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

The output is `None`.

I'm confused that why the output of `torch.where` is `tensor([0.])`?

### update

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([[1,2.], [3., 4]])
b = torch.tensor([-1., -1], requires_grad=True)
a[:,0] = b

(a[0, 0] * a[0, 1]).backward()
print(b.grad)
```

The output is `tensor([2., 0.])`. `(a[0, 0] * a[0, 1])` is not in any way related to `b[1]`, but the gradient of `b[1]` is `0` not `None`.

Answer (score 5):

Tracking based AD, like pytorch, works by *tracking*. You can't track through things that are not function calls intercepted by the library.  By using an `if` statement like this, there's no connection between `x` and `y`, whereas with `where`, `x` and `y` are linked in the expression tree.

Now, for the differences:

- In the first snippet, `0` is the correct derivative of the function `x ↦ x > 0 ? x : 2` at the point `-1` (since the negative side is constant).
- In the second snippet, as I said, `x` is not in any way related to `y` (in the `else` branch).  Therefore, the derivative of `y` given `x` is undefined, which is represented as `None`.

(You can do such things even in Python, but that requires more sophisticated technology like source transformation.  I don't thing it is possible with pytorch.)

Comment: I guess the  `0` gradient is equivalent to `None`, see my update.

Comment: No, it's still the same principle. In your new example, (a[0, 0] * a[0, 1]) is to be thought as a function of the whole of b. You backpropagate only through that part that is constant with repect to b[1]. I suggest you familiarize yourself a bit with the implementation details of AD systems in general, then this will become more easy to see.

Comment: Is there a tutorial for the implementation details of AD systems, especially for the in-place operation, there exist many weird phenomenon.

Comment: I have a collection of references [here](https://github.com/TuringLang/IRTracker.jl/blob/master/background.md), but it's quite Julia-focused. And mutability is rarely treated, because it makes things difficult.